# Javascript Set:Get Pointless?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

I have been experimenting with getters and setters with the following pattern:

```
var mytab = {
  _tab: undefined,
  get: function () {
    return this._tab;
  },
  set: function (tab) {
    this._tab = tab;
    return tab;
  }
}
```

My question is, given you have to access those methods explicitly, ie:

```
mytab.get();
mytab.set('thistab');
```

Why bother having `get` or `set` at all? Why not call them whatever you like? ie:

```
var mytab = {
  _tab: undefined,
  getthetab: function () {
    return this._tab;
  },
  setthetab: function (tab) {
    this._tab = tab;
    return tab;
  }
}
```

I may have missed some fundamental principle here, but both these `objects` behave exactly the same.

I assumed having special 'setters' and 'getters' would allow the object to be modified using it's object name, ie:

```
var a = mytab;
mytab = 'thistab';
```

Or even:

```
var a = mytab();
mytab() = 'thistab';
```

This is what I expected, and what I wanted, however those instructions give errors, namely that `mytab()` is not a function.

I would appreciate some clarity on what special significance the `set` and `get` object methods actually have.

Comment: Getters and setters are not meant to be used by calling get() and set() methods directly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, you **haven't** declared getters/setters. You've created an object with two methods called `get` and `set`.

To declare getters/setters, you'll have to choose an arbitrary name, and **prefix** it with `get` or `set`, like:

```js
var mytab = {
  _tab: undefined,
  get tab() {
    return this._tab;
  },
  set tab(tab) {
    this._tab = tab;
    return tab;
  }
}
```

In this case, they form a so-called accessor property, that has the chosen name:

```
console.log(mytab.get) //undefined
console.log(mytab.set) //undefined

mytab.tab = 'foo'
console.log(mytab._tab) //foo
mytab._tab = 'bar'
console.log(mytab.tab) //bar
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(mytab, 'tab')) /*
{
  get: function(){...},
  set: function(tab){...},
  ...
}
*/
```

---

However, you cannot overload operators or otherwise define a *single* getter/setter pair for your objects, that would allow you to assign a value or read a value from the object itself.

You can only define getters/setters for the properties on the object.

So,

```
var a = mytab
```

or

```
mytab = a
```

cannot be intercepted, and doesn't do what you expect (the first assigns the object itself to another variable (`a`), while the second reassigns the variable `mytab` with the value of `a` without even affecting / interacting with the object).

Comment: Sure but the question is *why* would you do this?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Because that way these functions are executed whenever you read from that property (get) or assign to that property (set), so getters/setters in Javascript are interceptor methods. That's actually a much nicer way to implement getters/setter than e.g. Java does.

Comment: This now makes more sense to me. I was under the impression that objects could delegate their values using this method, however I now realise such methods only apply to member elements. I will rename the variable to `options` or some other useful name and have `tab` as a child element with get:set functions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The following use case can illustrate advantage of using getters and setters

```js
var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  get fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
};
console.log(person.fullName);
```

Using getter we could use get fullName as if it was a property of person without the need of maintaining separate field.